# How to get permission levels for Files/Folders/Documents in Sharepoint using rest endpoints?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, permissions

I am using the following rest end point while trying to get permission levels for a particular file/document.

```
https://<web url>/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('<path to the file>')/getlimitedwebpartmanager(scope=1 or 0)
```

I am able to get hold of the file successfully. But how should I get hold of the permission levels now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I do to get the permission levels is by using the "$expand" query parameter equal to "ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/XXXX" where XXXX is Member, RoleDefinitionBindings, and so forth expanding out the chain as far as I need to get the user and permission level info that I need.  For example,

```
.../GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('')?$expand=ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/RoleDefinitionBindings,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Users
```

It took a lot of web searching to figure out that the "$expand" query parameter even existed but it's very useful to get all the info needed in one GET.  I subsequently add a "$select" parameter to the query to filter out just the pieces that my application uses.

**Edit:**
Also look at Radu's question and my follow-up answer below.  The answer to the question depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  To quote part of my answer:

> If you're dredging for all permissions had by all users, use my approach. However, you'll need sufficient rights to get that information. If you want to know the base permissions of the user you're using to make the request, use his approach. I have both use cases in my work so I, in fact, do both.

Comment: when I add the $expand parameter i get "2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException". The url works otherwise but it just downloads the file...

Comment: on a second check, the url without the extend param, actually returns the file metadata, but this is not enough

Comment: how do we achieve this for sharepoint 2010, since we cannot directly use an rest api for it

Comment: Years later this is still functional and useful for Sharepoint Online.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted solution didn't work for me. It seems that a user doesn't by default have permission to see RoleAssignments. But here's what I ended up doing.

I grabbed the effectiveBasePermissions by getting a response from
/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('my/relative/path')/ListItemAllFields/effectiveBasePermissions

I think this works for any item/folder in sharepoint by appending the /ListItemAllFields/effectiveBasePermissions to the url)

So, this returns the permission that the current user has for that file/item. The Permissions "object" is a set of 35 flags which are encoded in 64 bits (not all 64 bits are used - only 35). And these bits are provided by the endpoint as two integers (32 bits each) named:

- Low - representing the first 32 bits
- High - the next 32 bits in sequence, up to 64

Now, to see if the user has, for instance, editing permissions on that file, we need to look at the corresponding bit in this Low-High sequence. You can find what each bit in the sequence means, below:

```
    ViewListItems = 1,
    AddListItems = 2,
    EditListItems = 3,
    DeleteListItems = 4,
    ApproveItems = 5,
    OpenItems = 6,
    ViewVersions = 7,
    DeleteVersions = 8,
    CancelCheckout = 9,
    ManagePersonalViews = 10,
    ManageLists = 12,
    ViewFormPages = 13,
    AnonymousSearchAccessList = 14,
    Open = 17,
    ViewPages = 18,
    AddAndCustomizePages = 19,
    ApplyThemeAndBorder = 20,
    ApplyStyleSheets = 21,
    ViewUsageData = 22,
    CreateSSCSite = 23,
    ManageSubwebs = 24,
    CreateGroups = 25,
    ManagePermissions = 26,
    BrowseDirectories = 27,
    BrowseUserInfo = 28,
    AddDelPrivateWebParts = 29,
    UpdatePersonalWebParts = 30,
    ManageWeb = 31,
    AnonymousSearchAccessWebLists = 32,
    UseClientIntegration = 37,
    UseRemoteAPIs = 38,
    ManageAlerts = 39,
    CreateAlerts = 40,
    EditMyUserInfo = 41,
    EnumeratePermissions = 63
```

As you can see, some bits don't mean anything (like bit 11, 33, 34 etc)
So, we need to look at bit number 3 (for editing) from the first 32 bits to tell if user can edit this file/item/folder. We can just ignore the High bits. We must make a bitwise comparison with the integer which in binary format has only the 3rd bit set to 1 (the rest being 0). In this case this is 100 (this is the binary representation of 4). There is a formula for this, actually: binaryNr = 2^(bitIndex - 1). For our example, bitIndex is 3.
Now that we have the binaryNr we use it as a mask to find out if the third bit in the low sequence is 0 or 1:

hasEditingPermission = (binaryNr | LowSequence) == LowSequence

and here's a handy pseudocode function for the whole thing (^ is the power operator):

```
function hasPermission (low, high, bitIndex){
  var sequence = low;
  if (bitIndex >= 32){
    sequence = high;
    bit -= 32;
  }
  return ((2^(bitIndex - 1)) | sequence) == sequence
}
```

Comment: Indeed you are correct.  In the example I gave, I'm dredging permission information for all users as a user with sufficient credentials to do so.  As you show, I also use a variety of `/effectiveBasePermissions` combinations (web, list, file, folder) for getting that information for the user whose credentials are being used to make the REST call.
One difference I have is in `hasPermission()`.  I use the exact same code as you show above but I use:
`return (sequence & (1 << (permissionBitIndex - 1))) != 0;` (in my Java code).  Your bit comparison doesn't work properly for me, at least in Java.

Comment: I don't get it...1 << (permissionBitIndex - 1)  is equivalent to 2^(permissionBitIndex - 1). One of us is doing something wrong

Comment: Radu, I added an additional answer below to discuss `hasPermission()`.

Comment: @ThomasDoman the misunderstanding is the operator ^ . I was referring to the power operator. I edited the answer to clarify this. ^ stands for XOR in JAVA... of course it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Radu!  Just curious, what language has ^ as the power operator?  Your code had looked like JavaScript to me but in JavaScript it's also XOR.  Or, based on your edit, was it just intended to be purely pseudocode?

Comment: to checkm permission from the api result,
  `var permissions = new SP.BasePermissions();
       permissions.initPropertiesFromJson(data.d.EffectiveBasePermissions);
       
var hasPermissions = permissions .has(SP.PermissionKind.manageLists);`

Answer (score 0):

Radu made a great point in his answer for a different use case than I had given in my answer.  If you're dredging for all permissions had by all users, use my approach.  However, you'll need sufficient rights to get that information.  If you want to know the base permissions of the user you're using to make the request, use his approach.  I have both use cases in my work so I, in fact, do both.

However, as I commented to Radu in his answer, I had some trouble using his `hasPermission()` function.  I'm adding a new answer here to provide an example of why it didn't work for me:

I'm definitely **not** a expert bit twiddler but, in Java at least, `1 << (bitIndex-1)` is not equivalent to `2 ^ (bitIndex-1)` as Radu asserted in his comment.  Perhaps the overall expressions were intended to accomplish the same thing so here's an example where I discovered the XOR approach didn't work for me.

***Example:***
The permissions had by the user correspond to the permission list "Limited Access" (low = 134287360).  I want to check if the user has the "Open" permission, bit 17.  In binary, the low value (which becomes "sequence" in `hasPermission()`) is `1000000000010001000000000000`.  As you will see, bit 17 is set.  Running the expression `((2^(bitIndex - 1)) | sequence)` yields `1000000000010001000000010010` which obviously does not equal sequence as required to get a `true` response from `hasPermission()`.

So, not understanding or knowing for sure exactly what was intended by Radu's XOR approach, I decided to use a more straightforward, less obtuse way for testing for the presence of a bit.    Like so: `return (sequence & (1 << (bitIndex - 1))) != 0;` Taking 1 and shifting it `bitIndex-1` spaces to the left and then doing a bitwise AND not only makes it obvious what I'm trying to accomplish but it also works in every case I've tested.

Not being a bit twiddler as I said, I briefly considered whether there might be problems with signed values etc. (I'm using ints for high and low) but I don't think my approach really would suffer from any of that since I'm not shifting the ints themselves and the remainder of my logic is simply bitwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('<your file or folder url>')/ListItemAllFields/effectiveBasePermissions",
    type: "GET",
    headers: { Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function(data){
        var permissions = new SP.BasePermissions();
        permissions.initPropertiesFromJson(data.d.EffectiveBasePermissions);
        var hasPermissions = permissions.has(SP.PermissionKind.<any level to check>);
        //for example: var bool_has_editListItems =  permissions.has(SP.PermissionKind.editListItems);
    }
});
```

to check more levels, see [SP.PermissionKind list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee556747(v=office.14))